# How to Link Boost Shared Library Correctly

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, dynamic-linking

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, cmake 3.12.2, g++ 8.3.0. I have a very simple program using Boost Filesystem component;

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    fs::path absolute_arg0 = fs::absolute(argv[0]);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << absolute_arg0 << std::endl;
}
```

And cmake to build it

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(demo VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

# Set default build type, if none is given
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug" CACHE STRING
        "Choose the type of build, options are: Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel."
        FORCE)
endif()

# Set default language settings
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# Set default compiler options
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    list(APPEND common_flags -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated -Werror)
    list(APPEND common_flags -Wshadow -Wunused -Wuninitialized)
    list(APPEND common_flags -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wfloat-equal)
    list(APPEND common_flags -fno-strict-aliasing)
    list(APPEND cxx_only_flags -Wsign-promo -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wctor-dtor-privacy)
    list(APPEND cxx_only_flags -Woverloaded-virtual -Wold-style-cast)

    add_compile_options(${common_flags})
    add_compile_options("$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:${cxx_only_flags}>")
endif()

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system)

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
message(" Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ")
message(" Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ")

install(TARGETS ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${APD_INSTALL_ROOT}/opt/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}/bin)
```

with

```
Boost_LIBRARIES=/path/to/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so;/path/to/lib/libboost_system-mt.so
```

But when I run the executable it gives me;

> error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.68.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The linker links against libboost_filesystem.so.1.68.0 not against libboost_filesystem-mt.so. Why is that so?

Comment: have you tried using the Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED cmake option (set to On)? Have a look at the [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html).

Comment: @compor I just did after your comment, it did not work.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that error during loading signifies that the loader was not able to find that library. Can you export the correct path in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and try again. At least that error would be fixed and we could go back to the build, where the linker is involved. Lastly, make sure that those libraries actually exist at that path.

Comment: @compor The LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty. I set it using set command but still does not work.

Comment: you should do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/boost/library/` in the shell where you are trying to run your program, not via cmake.

Comment: @compor yes, it works that way. but how to fix inside cmake :/
I have no idea how to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203324/discussion-between-compor-and-tonyparker).